# Regexp match any uppercase characters except a particular string

Tags: regex

I want to match all lines that have any uppercase characters in them but ignoring the string **A_**

To add to the complication I want to ignore everything after a different string, e.g. an open comment

Here are examples of what should and shouldnt match

**Matches:**

- fooBar
- foo Bar foo
- A_fooBar
- fooBar /* Comment */

**Non Matches** (C_ should not trigger a match)

- A_foobar
- foo A_bar
- foobar
- foo bar foo bar
- foobar /* Comment */

thanks :)

Comment: A_fooBar has a A_ in it and is listed in the matches, I don't understand (expecially since A_foobar is listed as not a match).

Comment: I'm doing this testing using powergrep. @ C. Ross, A_fooBar is a match because of the B in bar, not because of the A_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should (also?) do it:

```
(?!A_)[A-Z](?!((?!/\*).)*\*/)
```

A short explanation:

```
(?!A_)[A-Z]     # if no 'A_' can be seen, match any uppercase letter
(?!             # start negative look ahead
  ((?!/\*).)    #   if no '/*' can be seen, match any character (except line breaks)
  *             #   match zero or more of the previous match
  \*/           #   match '*/'
)               # end negative look ahead
```

So, in plain English:

> Match any uppercase except 'A_' and also not an uppercase if '*/' can be seen without first encountering '/*'.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(?<!A_)[a-zA-Z]+
```

`(?!...)` is called a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

As for your specific problem, it's kind of cheating but try:

```
^([#\.]|(?<!A_))[A-Za-z]{2,}
```

I get:

```
fooBar => fooBar
foo Bar foo => foo
A_fooBar (no match)
fooBar /* Comment */ => fooBar
A_foobar (no match)
foo A_bar => foo
foobar => foobar
foo bar foo bar => foo
foobar /* Comment */ => foobar
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont want to match [a-zA-Z]. This is what i have so far ^([A-Z]|[#.])[^{]*?(?<=[A-Z]) now i need to exclude any matches that  have A_ as their only uppercase characters

Comment: That expression doesn't make a lot of sense. I'm running a little test and it only matches the ones with A at the front.

Comment: the expression above only matches the uppercase characters, it checks the start of the line and allows for it to start with # or a . (as its CSS) [A-Z]|[#.]. Then it does anything other than a {, stops and looks behind for any uppercase characters. This works fine for me. The only complication i have now is preventing it from matching if it sees A_ when it looks back

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

```
/([B-Z]|A[^_]|A$)/
```

I would remove the comment at an earlier stage, if at all possible.

Test:

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @matches = (
"fooBar",
"foo Bar foo",
"A_fooBar",
"fooBar /* Comment */");

my @nomatches = (
"A_foobar",
"foo A_bar",
"foobar",
"foo bar foo bar",
"foobar /* Comment */");

my $regex = qr/([B-Z]|A[^_]|A$)/;

for my $m (@matches) {
    $m =~ s:/\*.*$::;
    die "FAIL $m" unless $m =~ $regex;
}
for my $m (@nomatches) {
    $m =~ s:/\*.*$::;
    die "FAIL $m" unless $m !~ $regex;
}
```

Try it: http://codepad.org/EJhWtqkP

Comment: thanks Kinopiko, love the simplicity of your solution. I am writing expressions for use in static code analysis, so i wont actualy be removing anything. This is why i dont want to do a match inside a comment.

Comment: Just copy the string and do a match on the copied one.

Answer (score 0):

This one does it, although the comment handling isn't extremely robust.  (It assumes that a comment is always at the end of the line.)

```
.*((A(?!_)|([B-Z]))(?<!/\*.*)).*\r\n
```

Comment: This looks pretty promising Mike, thanks. I think its falling down when there are multiple _, still looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a single regex?  In perl, you could do something like:

if ($string =~ /[A-Z]/  && $string !~ /A_/)

Its not as cool as a single expression with lookback, but its probably easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?:[^A-Z/]|A_|/(?!\*))*+[A-Z]
```

This will work in any flavor that supports possessive quantifiers, e.g. PowerGrep, Java and PHP. The .NET flavor doesn't, but it does support atomic groups:

```
^(?>(?:[^A-Z/]|A_|/(?!\*))*)[A-Z]
```

If neither of those features is available, you can use another lookahead to prevent it matching the `A_` on the rebound:

```
^(?:[^A-Z/]|A_|/(?!\*))*(?!A_)[A-Z]
```