# Regex in PHP to find last upcase char from the Camel Case

Tags: php, regex, capitalize, ucfirst

I want to match in PHP the last capitalize (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) character in the string.

To add to the complication I want to ignore everything after a different string, e.g. a sequence of uppercases that not capitalized or in camel case style.

Here follow some examples of what should and shouldnt match

**Matches:**

```
Foobar => Expected char: F
fooBar  => Expected char: B
A_fooBar  => Expected char: B
fooBAR => Expected char: B (Most complicated situation)
```

**No matches:**

```
foo A_bar
foobar
foo bar foo bar
foobar /* Comment */
```

So far I've tried the following regex:

```
(?!A_)[A-Z](?!((?!/\*).)*\*/)
```

but with no luck. From Question: the [Regexp match any uppercase characters except a particular string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667237/regexp-match-any-uppercase-characters-except-a-particular-string) (Very similar situation)

**@edit**

And another regex

```
/([A-Z])[^A-Z\W]*$/
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dyq-3h7

Comment: Which regex have you tried so far?

Comment: `(?!A_)[A-Z](?!((?!/\*).)*\*/)`

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm edietd the question and added the example in the php fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this matches where appropriate, and will ignore your other examples as well.

```
^\w*?(?<![A-Z_])([A-Z])(?!_)
```

[See this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pfc-f9y)

Comment: If it's not asking too much can you explain your regex?

Comment: No problem.  I'm looking for zero or more word characters (not greedy) at the start of the line (^\w*?), then any uppercase letter ([A-Z]) that is not preceded with an uppercase character or underscore (?<![A-Z_]) and is also not followed by an underscore (?!_).

Answer (score 1):

try this

`/([A-Z])([A-Za-z]|[^_\*\/])*$/`

this works with every of your examples:

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sgb-7m

Comment: I'm creating fiddle and trying now!

Comment: oh sorry i havent seen this `fooBAR => Expected char: B (Most complicated situation)`. need an extra minute to think :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you basically want the last uppercase letter that is not preceded by another uppercase letter. In that case, try this:

```
/.*(?<![A-Z])([A-Z])/
```

Then just get the first subpattern.

Comment: This will match the /* Comment */ line I believe.

Comment: Matches, but thanks for example! I will keep trying. See yor example http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/802-hgp